# How to remove sql server date time default value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am pretty new to sql and I keep getting the sql default value 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000.  I just want the field to be empty. I thought if I put '' the empty string it would use that instead of the default value.  I commented the line where I think the problem is.  I have tried other ways like ISNULL and Convert but that does not work. Thanks in advance and if you can explain how the default date works and how to override it that would be much appreciated.

```
DECLARE @custAccount nvarchar(20)                        

SET @custAccount='CUS07869'

SELECT 'SM' as [Origin]
  ,'SN' as [Action Code]
  ,ST.PurchOrderFormNum as [Order Number]
  ,SL.ITEMID AS [LINE ITEM]
  ,SL.QTYORDERED as [Quantity]
  ,S.SHIPMENTDATE as [Action Date]
  ,S.TRACKINGNUMBER as [TRACKING]
  ,ISNULL(S.SHIPMENTDATE, '') as [DATE_SHIPPED]
  ,S.SHIPMETHOD as [Carrier]
FROM SalesTable ST                         
  INNER JOIN GBP_Shipping S                         
  ON ST.SalesId=S.SalesId AND ST.DataAreaId=S.DataAreaId                        
  INNER JOIN SalesLine SL              
  ON ST.SalesId=SL.SalesId AND ST.DataAreaId=SL.DataAreaId                        
WHERE ST.CUSTACCOUNT=@custAccount                         
  AND S.SHIPMENTDATE = convert(varchar, getdate(), 111)             
  AND ST.salestype!=4              
UNION

SELECT   'SM' as [Origin]
  ,'AN' as [Action Code]
  ,ST.PurchOrderFormNum as [Order Number]
  ,SL.ITEMID AS [LINE ITEM]
  ,SL.QTYORDERED as [Quantity]
  ,replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 111), '/', '') as [Action Date]
  ,'' as [TRACKING]
  ,'' as [DATE_SHIPPED]   --I think this is the problem           
  ,'' as [Carrier]          
FROM SalesTable ST                                         
  INNER JOIN SalesLine SL              
  ON ST.SalesId=SL.SalesId AND ST.DataAreaId=SL.DataAreaId                        
WHERE ST.CUSTACCOUNT=@custAccount                         
  AND ST.CREATEDDATE = convert(varchar, getdate(), 111)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first part of your union sets the type of the data in the column.

try

```
,case when S.SHIPMENTDATE is null then ''
else Convert(VarChar(10),S.SHIPMENTDATE)
end as DATE_SHIPPED
```

instead
of

```
,ISNULL(S.SHIPMENTDATE, '') as [DATE_SHIPPED]
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked.  Also I just changed the '.' between varchar(10) and S.SHIPMENTDATE to a ',' in the convert function. But other than that it works nicely so thanks again I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have an "empty" default date -- you have to set something there. Under the hood they are stored as a binary value, and a binary value of 0 gets transalted to something; here, I'd guess you are using smalldatetime, and I'm reasonably sure `0` = `Jan 1, 1900`. (Datetime of 0 gets you something in 1753, when the Gregorian calendar officialy started. I'm not sure what coin they flipped for the date/time datatypes new to SQL 2008.)

If you want "no date", you'll probably have to use NULL values, and check for them wherever relevant with the `isnull` function. Irritating, perhaps, but IMHO it's one of the most legit uses of NULL values in SQL.